# Displaying database data in JSP using myBatis

Tags: jsp, mybatis

I am fairly new to myBatis and JSP. I am at my learning stage and want to know a simple thing. I have a table books in mySQL and am able to perform basic operations on it using myBatis. But I want the data to be displayed in a JSP page.

Here is the code:

Book.java

```
package ibatis;

public class Book {

    private int id;
    private String author;
    private String title;
    private String year;
    private String remark;

    //Getters and Setters
```

}

Book.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<!DOCTYPE sqlMap      
    PUBLIC "-//ibatis.apache.org//DTD SQL Map 2.0//EN"      
    "http://ibatis.apache.org/dtd/sql-map-2.dtd">

<sqlMap namespace="Book">

<typeAlias alias="Book" type="ibatis.Book"/>

  <select id="selectAllBooks" resultClass="ibatis.Book">
    select * from books
  </select>

</sqlMap>
```

sqlMapConfig.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE sqlMapConfig 
    PUBLIC "-//ibatis.apache.org//DTD SQL Map Config 2.0//EN"
    "http://ibatis.apache.org/dtd/sql-map-config-2.dtd">

<sqlMapConfig>

 <transactionManager type="JDBC" commitRequired="false">
  <dataSource type="SIMPLE">
   <property name="JDBC.Driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
   <property name="JDBC.ConnectionURL" 
       value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/books"/>
   <property name="JDBC.Username" value="root"/>
   <property name="JDBC.Password" value=""/>
   </dataSource>
 </transactionManager>

 <sqlMap resource="ibatis/Book.xml"/>

</sqlMapConfig>
```

Main.java

```
package ibatis;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.ibatis.io.Resources;

import com.ibatis.sqlmap.client.SqlMapClient;
import com.ibatis.sqlmap.client.SqlMapClientBuilder;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args)
          throws IOException, SQLException {

    Reader reader = Resources.getResourceAsReader("sqlMapConfig.xml");
    SqlMapClient sqlMap = SqlMapClientBuilder.buildSqlMapClient(reader);

    System.out.println("List of all Books");
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<Book> books = (List<Book>)sqlMap.queryForList("selectAllBooks");

    for (Book a : books) {
        System.out.println(a.getAuthor() + " : " + a.getTitle());
    }
  }
}
```

This is a basic myBatis Java program. Any steps towards building the jsp page would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What is the framework you have in mind to link up between the jsp page and ibatis/mybatis?

Possible (not exhausive) options include:

- Struts
- Spring MVC

Hope it helps

Comment: I plan to use Spring MVC framework. Could you guide me as to how its done.?

Comment: See if this github project is helpful to you https://github.com/lorcanluo/spring-mvc-mybatis-tpl